# why not java replaced Serializable with @Serializable annotation

Tags: java, serialization

after the introduction of annotation, why not java replaced Serializable with @Serializable annotation

Comment: first, because of back compatibility

Answer (score 7):

Annotations are not inherited. The Serializable interface is inherited.  This means that not only would be break compatibility to remove the interface, it might not be possible to replace it with an annotation as the behaviour is not the same.

Another difference is you can write

```
void method(Serializable s)
```

but you cannot do the same for an annotation, although ObjectOutputStream.writeObject takes an `Object` in any case.

Answer (score 1):

I think mostly because it would mean that **a lot** of old code that doesn't use the annotation would start giving compiler warnings all over the place.

Serializable is not the only thing that could have been deprecated, but for the sake of backwards compatibility hasn't.